# How to avoid printing the default values (argparse) in the help message (-h, --help)

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

Here is the code.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
        description="infomedia"
    )
    parser.add_argument("file", help="path to file")

    parser.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--info",
        type=str,
        default="False",
        help="get information about",
    )

    cli_args = parser.parse_args()

    worker = Worker(
        cli_args.input,
        cli_args.info,
    )

    worker._application()
```

When the program is running with -h / --help it shows the default values.

```
positional arguments:
  file                  path to file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INFO, --info INFO  get information about (default: False)
```

How to avoid printing the default values? Or is there a way to define the default values of this code in a different way?

Comment: why are you using `formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter`?

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry. I thought it should always be defined. It was in a guide and I added that to my code. Is that the problem?

Comment: yes, that specifies an alternative formatter, one that displays the defaults.  That is explained in the official python reference.

Comment: You want the default formatter: `argparse.ArgumentParser(description="infomedia")`   https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new class inheriting from `argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` and override `_get_help_string` method and pass your newly created class which is `MyHelpFormatter` in the below example as `formatter_class` in `ArgumentParser` constructor. Here is the example code which can help you:

```
import argparse

class MyHelpFormatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter):
    def _get_help_string(self, action):
        return action.help

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=MyHelpFormatter,
        description="infomedia",
    )
    parser.add_argument("file", help="path to file")

    parser.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--info",
        type=str,
        default="False",
        help="get information about",
    )

    cli_args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's a round about way of reverting the behavior to the default `HelpFormatter`.  Why not just omit that parameter?   `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="infomedia")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` to suppress showing a default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want more like:

```
parser.add_argument("--info", help="get information", action="store_true")
```

Comment: At this point, specification of --info on the command line will set parse_args().info to be boolean True. If you needed that to be the string, you could cast it with str(parse_args().info)